# Autofilter - Number Filters - Equals... is filtering TEXT?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have run into a problem using Excel Autofilter when using "Number Filters"

Problem details and setup: In a table Having a column of NUMBERS, formatted as number, using 0 decimals and having thousand separator, let's say we have a value of 1015 that formatted will be "1,015".

Then using the "Number Filters" - "Equals..." option then when I complete the box with "1015" will return no rows, but if I write exactly as is it displayed - "1,015" then will get to my data.

So why "Number Filters" is filtering data as TEXT?...

Thanks for any kind of advice.

Comment: because "1,015" is a formatted string of text, whereas 1015 is a numeric value.

Comment: @Frank Thomas Sorry but I can't understand what you mean. The cell is formatted as number. So I expect to be able type 1015 to filter it. Am I wrong? What can I do to be able to filter numbers just by typing the digits just like the video in this page at 4:20. [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Filter-data-in-a-table-7fbe34f4-8382-431d-942e-41e9a88f6a96)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Excel tries to be "smart" by assuming that your column values are "text" even if you set the column as a "Number". 
To ensure that you do indeed have numeric values in that column instead of text values that contain numbers do the following:

1) Multiply the whole column with 1 (You can use the Paste Special function to multiply a range of cells by a number, in your case 1)

2) Re-run your filter.

Comment: Still the same. typing 1000 finds no match. while typing 1,000 in equal filter dialog box finds 3 matches. Can you upload a test file please? Million thanks for your assist.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have actually stumbled upon a bug.

This is not the expected behavior for autofiltering.

If you use a custom filter with "less than 1016" AND "bigger than 1014" suppose you want to filter on 1015, then it should work.

It has been reported elsewhere too.